# What is an assumption in Isar?

Tags: isabelle, isar

I have the following code:

```
lemma assumes "A" shows "A ∧ A"
proof -
  show "A ∧ A"
    apply (rule conjI)
    apply assumption
```

Now, applying conjunction introduction works, but applying the assumption does not.

Seemingly, `assumes` would introduce an assumption, wouldn't it?

The very same thing happens when I do

```
lemma a_imp_a_and_a: "A ⟶ A ∧ A"
proof (rule impI)
  assume A
  show "A ∧ A" apply (rule conjI)
   apply assumption
```

Again, I've thought `assume` would introduce an assumption that can be solved by

```
apply assumption
```

but it does not work.

What is an assumption in Isar that can be solved by `apply assumption`?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the question is about how assumptions can be referenced to in an Isar proof.
One way to use assumptions is through the `assms` keyword like this:

`lemma assumes "A" shows "A∧A" using assms by simp`

Or, if you want on explicit rule application you can you use `from` and quote the assumption twice as `conjI` has two assumptions:

```
lemma assumes "A" shows "A∧A"
proof -
  from ‹A› ‹A› show ?thesis by (rule conjI)
qed
```

You can also use the `assms` keyword in the direct rule application but again you have to repeat `assms(1)` to match the `conjI` lemma:

```
lemma assumes "A" shows "A∧A"
proof -
  from assms(1) assms(1) show ?thesis by (rule conjI)
qed
```

I checked this in Isabelle/ZF, but it should be the same in Isabelle/HOL.

Comment: My question is what I wrote: what is an assumption in the sense that I could use "apply assumption" to use it. But anyway, thanks, now I see how assumptions created by the "assumes" keyword can be referenced in an Isar proof.